# Pass Callback function to different Activity

Tags: android, asynchronous

I am trying to perform a callback within a Async Task (communicate to Cloud server) to different Activity method.  As my design will call the same Async Task in different Activity.

Now I am using the method which require checking the Activity name.  Is there a way I could pass a generic method function (like C code) into "LoginAccount" during the call ?

```
public void loginAccount(final Activity activity, final String email, final String password) {
```

Start a Async task, then
  .......
  return of Async task here

```
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Object value) {

          String strName = activity.getClass().getSimpleName();

          if (strName.equals("MainActivity"))
                ((MainActivity)activity).updateDeviceName();
          else if (strName.equals("LoginActivity"))
                ((LoginActivity)activity).processLoginResult();
    } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass functions as parameters in java but the closest you can get to this kind of behavior is to pass a `Runnable` object.

#### [Runnable | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why does your task do very seemingly very different things? You should probably just make two different classes that extend AsyncTask<>. Then use the respective AsyncTask in each Activity.

Comment: The reason I try to do this is, the project has a common Class now for Cloud access (6 different functions within a Class) to a IOT device.  This Cloud access functions are being used in multiple Activity page.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you can't do what I suggested

Answer (score 0):

I end up using different approach to resolve this problem. I had created a "Service" to handle the Cloud activity at background.  Each Activity would bind to Service and use Messenger to trigger the Async method.

This case, I have prevented Activity being destroyed and callback is gone.  As Service will not be changed until Apps is closed.